# Emgu.CV Error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` When Fetching Frame C#

Tags: c#, opencv, video

I'm trying to use Emgu.CV to load frames from a .mp4 file, but I can't get it working. For whatever reason I'm getting an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error on a different line depending on whether I'm running in build mode or developer mode (in Visual Studio). Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace Cloth_Simulation
{
    internal class FrameLoader
    {
        public static Image<Gray, byte> FetchFrame(string filepath, int frameNumber)
        {

            using (var capture = new VideoCapture(filepath)) // Where the error occurs in release mode
            {
                capture.Set(CapProp.PosFrames, frameNumber);
                using (var frame = capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Gray, byte>()) // Where the error occurs in debug mode
                {
                    if (frame != null)
                    {
                        // Return the frame (or you can return the specific data you need)
                        return frame.Clone();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Frame not found or cannot be loaded.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static Vector2 GetWidthAndHeight(Image<Gray, byte> frame)
        {
            return new Vector2(frame.Width, frame.Height);
        }
        public static int PixelValue(Image<Gray, byte> frame, Vector2 coords)
        {
            byte pixelValue = frame.Data[(int)coords.Y, (int)coords.X, 0];
            return pixelValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas what the problem is? I'm sure the video file I'm using isn't corrupted and all the file paths are right. Thanks!

Comment: as far as i know, reading video file in encoding format like mp4 is not as simple as thought. U maybe need an util like ffmpeg to decode each frame, maybe i'm maybe  formats like mp4 are default supported by Emgu.CV